# Sync Two Exchange accounts or Ready Only access to subfolders

Tags: windows-7, exchange-2007, windows-sbs-2008, exchange

This is two questions kind of.

The situation is as follows. I am running SBS 2008 with Exchange 2007.

There is a shared account which has subfolders to keep track of the process of jobs that are coming into the company (ie: sales)

I need to give other people in the company read access to this mailbox not full control. When I give ready only access to the root other users can only see the Inbox and not subfolders. Permissions have to be applied to each folder.

One solution I have considered is creating a secondary mailbox that everyone could have full access too which would have a one way sync from the sales mailbox to the secondary mailbox. Then people could see what was happening without messing up the main mailbox by accident (at worst they would mess up the secondary mailbox)

Ideally I could find a way to propgate the READ ONLY Permissiosn to all the subfolders. I have tried using PFDavAdmin to do this but have not been able to get it to connect successfully from Windows 7 To Exchange 2007

Any idea on how to 
 1. Propogate permissions (get PFDavAdmin to work??!)
 2. Sync mailboxes
 3. Other solution?

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is possible to upgrade your Exchange to 2010 or to upgrade SBS to 2011 version that includes Exchange 2010 then you would be able to use this new tool to propogate the permissions

http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2009/12/04/453399.aspx

Comment: Hmmm this looks like the most work but I was thinking of upgrading anyways, it may be a good solution

Answer (score 2):

You're probably going to have to use third party software. One example is this:
http://www.codetwo.com/exchange-folder-sync/
Set it up to sync the inbox to a public folder or additional mailbox.

Comment: Looks like this software would do the sync but is more expensive then i was planning on for this functionality

Answer (score 1):

Check for the following URL with screenshot for managing permission using pvdavadmin

http://www.msexchange.org/articles/PFDavAdmin-tool-Part1.html
http://www.msexchange.org/articles/PFDavAdmin-tool-Part2.html

This should help you with your permission issue.